# How to create a DataFrame from records/rows

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have data structured like this:

```
records = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)]
```

I want a DataFrame like this

```
A | 1
B | 2
C | 3
```

How to achieve that most efficiently in Julia?

In python I would do a `pandas.DataFrame.from_records(records)`.

**EDIT**: I am looking for an approach which works for an arbitrary number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
julia> using DataFrames
julia> records = [("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)]

julia> DataFrame(x=first.(records),y=last.(records))
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x   │ y │
├─────┼─────┼───┤
│ 1   │ "A" │ 1 │
│ 2   │ "B" │ 2 │
│ 3   │ "C" │ 3 │
```

Note the `f.(args)` calls which broadcast `f` over all elements of args. `first` and `last` take the respective elements from the tuples, but an anonymous function could select any elements from tuples.

**UPDATE:**

In the case of many columns, the following might be more useful:

```
julia> n = length(records[1])
julia> DataFrame([[r[i] for r in records] for i=1:n],[Symbol("x$(i)") for i=1:n])
3×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x1  │ x2 │
├─────┼─────┼────┤
│ 1   │ "A" │ 1  │
│ 2   │ "B" │ 2  │
│ 3   │ "C" │ 3  │
```

This uses Julia features such as, array comprehension, string interpolation (which could be useful to look up if the expression is unclear)

Comment: Is there a generic way of doing so, without specifying each column?
say, I have records with 100 columns...